# mySQL: Get data from two tables with grouping by Date with unique ID

Tags: php, mysql

There are two Stackoverflow questions on how to group tables together by date and I can get it to work. My problem is I only want records that belong to a unique client ID IE Where client_id = x

My tables are:

```
TABLE INVOICE
invoice_id
client_id
invoice_number
invoice_amount
invoice_date

TABLE PAYMENT
payment_id
invoice_id
payment_amount
payment_date
```

At the moment my mySQL statement reads through the whole database. How do I get all invoice and payment details just for one client? IE WHERE client_id = x

My mySQL statement is:

```
SELECT payment_id AS idno, payment_amount AS debit, NULL as credit, payment_date 
AS added_on FROM payment 
UNION ALL 
SELECT invoice_id AS idno, NULL, invoice_total AS credit, invoice_date AS added_on FROM invoice 
WHERE client_id = 24 
ORDER BY added_on
```

Do I have to have the same amount of columns from each table? How do I identify from which table the data comes from?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM invoice i
JOIN payment p ON p.invoice_id = i.invoice_id
WHERE i.client_id= 24
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how the `UNION`, but i do know that your 2 two queries need the same amount of columns, just like you did.

I think the reason for your sql statement reading through the whole table is because your two tables are not joined, to do this you can do like @Sid-Hussain mentioned, by joining them in your first `SELECT`. You then just need to add   `WHERE client_id = 24` on the your first `SELECT`